# insert specific text line with multiple numbers of 60 at the end of each line, in a "output.txt" file

Tags: batch-file

Please help me to create a script to insert specific text line with multiple numbers of 60 at the end of each line, in a output text file

i have specific text like:  specific_text60

when i run the script, the generated output text file content is like:

specific_text60

specific_text120

specific_text180

specific_text240

.....

specific_text64800

and the lines end with the multiple of 60 end at the specified number, in my case 64800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "incr=60, end=64800"
set text=specific_text
set outfile=output.txt

for /L %%I in (%incr%, %incr%, %end%) do >>"%outfile%" echo(%text%%%I
```

---

If you want the number at the beginning of the line instead of the end, move the `%%I` to the other side of `%text%` like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "incr=60, end=64800"
set text=specific_text
set outfile=output.txt

for /L %%I in (%incr%, %incr%, %end%) do >>"%outfile%" echo(%%I%text%
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @bahrep - While this comment may address some other answer, it is better to include it as a comment to the essential answer you intended, and not randomly on some page that has nothing to do with what you're commenting on.  Comments posted on wrong pages can become invalid if the... oh, it's just invalid.

Comment: if i want the number at the beging of each lines

Comment: for /L %%I in (%incr%, %incr%, %end%) do >>"%outfile%" echo(%%I%text%

Comment: @roro that's not me, that's SO review tools.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(for /l %%i in (60,60,64800) do echo specific_text%%i)>out.txt
```

Comment: Ya, I like yours better if you'll change your start value to 60 and get rid of the `if %%i neq 0` part.